# How to use this psd font?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

I've used psd font in the past with photopea, as i dont have full shop. Just photopea and gimp at moment.

I am trying to use a .psd text font, that has honey drops in  it, i can load it using photopea but when i click the layer, the text does not change. Can anyone help me identify, where im going wrong ?

I need to change it to say " Flavours" - the current .psd template says "pop candy" but when i edit layer, it doesn't change the bubble type font.

[image]

So I need to edit this .psd so it says - Flavours and with honey drops around it but it does not seem to work with photopea or gimp.

Here is where i found the font

https://www.pixeden.com/photoshop-text-effects/psd-candy-text-effect

Can someone please tell me where im going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Photopea can edit this. I just tried it.

See example

[image]

The words pop and candy have two text layers each, so you have to double click the "T" icon in the layers panel for each text layer associated with it, and retype the words.

GIMP doesn't support Photoshop layer effects, so this won't work in GIMP. Although that's not to say you couldn't create something similar with GIMP from scratch.

Oh and by the way, there is no such thing as a PSD font. The font is called [Pacifico](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Pacifico?query=pacifico) - you'd need to install the font on your computer before you can use it in software such as Photoshop or GIMP.

Comment: Thank you so much... howe3ver, the browney/gold font, is what i need. I need it to be that 3D bubble effect, with the honey drops, but how do i do it and export it ? thanks again

Comment: @CandyShop, Is it possible you accidentally changed the layer name only? The simplest way to activate the text edit mode is to double click that **T** icon in the layers panel (on the right side). I guess it's worth to mention that it seems like you need to edit two text layers per row cause there's some stacked styling going on.

Comment: It's created with layer effects such as bevel and emboss, on a normal font.  Font are just plain until you add colours.

Answer (score 0):

If you rasterize a text layer and paste to it anything which has the same color as the original text you get that anything with the same honey effect.

Here's the text Pop all effects disabled. All other layers are disabled in the layers panel.

[image]

(it's text along a path for the slightly curved appearance)

Here's my new text after rasterizing the layer. It's drawn with a brush. As well I could paste something from another image.

[image]

I guess Photopea do not offer fancy fonts, but you can make your text as a bitmap image elsewhere.

[image]

This it is after the effects are again enabled in the layers panel. Text Candy is enabled, too for a reference.

[image]

I worked in Photoshop but there's nothing that cannot be done in Photopea. That program opens the image perfectly (checked).

Do not expect you can import this to GIMP. There are no layer styles. You must start from scratch to get something resembling. Photoshop has layer styles, smart objects and adjustment layers which make "place your own text or image" possible. GIMP has none of them.